# Eclipse Jobs stay in the Progress View after returning an OK status

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, jobs

I have a an Eclipse Job class similar to the following:

```
public class MyCustomJob extends Job {
   @Override
   protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
      MyObject.blockingMethod();
      return Status.OK_STATUS;
   }
}
```

When I execute this job and it exits correctly, the bottom-right where the progress is listed while it is running still shows the name of the now completed job, but without any progress bar. [image: Lingering Job name]

If I double click in the region where the name of the job still is, the Progress View opens as expected, but shows that the job has finished. If I click the "x" to clear the job, it disappears from the view, but if I close the view and reopen it, it comes right back. [image: Lingering job in Progress View]

How can I remove the name of the job from the bottom-right of the display and guarantee that if I clear the Finished job from the Progress View that is actually being dismissed?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Jobs are kept like this only if they specifically ask to be kept by setting a property (or exit with an error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the return path for any async UI execs that could affect status. Changing
from:

```
Platform.getDefault().asyncExec(runnable)
```

to

```
Platform.getDefault().syncExec(runnable)
```

fixed this issue